# how to use XMLRPC in C#

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

I need to make XMLRPC calls from my C# application and I failed to find any help with that. When I used XMLRPC from Ruby, it's that simple:

```
server = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://server/api.php")
result = server.call("remote.procedure", [1, [['crit1', 'crit2', 'crit3']]])
```

is there any similar library for C#?

Answer (score 22):

It's very simple to use the xml-rpc.net library, here is what you need to do:

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://url_to_your_server/api.php")]
public interface ISumAndDiff : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("your.remote.procedure")]
    string testMyClient(string test);
}

ISumAndDiff proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<ISumAndDiff>();

string ret = proxy.testMyClient("test");
```

Comment: I have only one nitpick with xml-rpc.net: it doesn't support optional parameters.

Answer (score 21):

See if this library works for you
https://code.google.com/p/xmlrpcnet/

Comment: The problem with this library is that its quite dated and isn't compatible with either Windows Store or Phone apps and doesn't support async as well. There aren't any alternatives I know of at this time.

Comment: This library is open source, and is readily available (http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpcnet/source/checkout). I'm sure you could fork it and port it to these newer and more recent platforms :)